# How to write a method that accepts and returns an array with conditions

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a method that accepts and returns an array of the total product of all positive numbers only. Thank you!

```
def positive_product(nums)

    nums.reject(&:negative?).inject(:*)

end


puts positive_product([5, 4, 3])
puts positive_product([-1, 2, -4, 2])
puts positive_product([-2, 4, 1])
puts positive_product([2, 1])
```

Comment: What's wrong with your solution?

Comment: It works, but I'm trying to make my output into an array.

Comment: The product result in this case is a Numeric, not an array. Anyway, maybe like this? `[nums.reject(&:negative?).inject(:*)]`

Comment: [Solved] Omg. Thank you! I did try that, but I forgot to switch puts into print!!

Comment: Voted to close since this is solved. You can consider making your own answer.